# Determine when a canvas is resized

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, resize, dom-events

I am trying to determine when a `canvas` is resized to repaint it.

Context: my `canvas` is inserted in a flex layout and its height gets set by the flexbox model and changes depending on other layout elements whose content and size may dynamically vary (e.g., the result of an AJAX request inserts texts in a nearby span, which causes the `canvas` to grow by, say, 10 pixels vertically).

It seems that the `resize` event is only sent to the window — so the resize event does not do the trick here, as the canvas may also change its size when the window does not.

How can I get notified when my `canvas` is resized?

Comment: try to store `height` and `width` of `canvas` in variables, and check them after each AJAX request. If one of tham has changed -> repaint canvas with new sizes (and don't forget to store new values!).

Comment: Yeah, thing is, the AJAX request if just one of several ways the size could change. Ideally, I don't want to keep track of all the ways manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If multiple parts of your code will change your canvas size, then you must indeed refactor each scriptlet to notify you when it changes the canvas size.

An easy way to do this is to create a resizing function that any scriptlet must use to resize the canvas. If that function is called, you know a scriptlet has resized the canvas:

```
function resizeCanvas(canvas,w,h){
    canvas.width=w;
    canvas.height=h;
    // All canvas resizing will flow to this point
    // so respond to the resizing here.
    console.log('The canvas has been resized');
}
```

Comment: Thanks mark. Thing is, I have to find every piece of code that may have as a side effect that the layout has changed and that the canvas's size may have changed as well. This is cumbersome.

Comment: Yes, but you are a coder and that's what we coders do when faced with a design requirement. Grab a cup of coffee and go to it!! :-)

Comment: I suspect you are over-horribilizing your task. Put the code in a text editor and "find" `.width` and `.height`. These are the only ways a canvas can be manually resized. Change these into calls to `resizeCanvas` Then (as @AndrewEvt says in his comment) listen for `window.onresize` and check for canvas width / height changes by the browser. Call `resizeCanvas` if you notice a change there. Not a horrible task. ;-)

Comment: The size of the canvas is automatically changed by the flexbox layout in response to the change of other elements in the same layout. I never directly change the canvas's size myself.

Comment: Flexbox containers trigger changes in response to window resizes by the user. So listening for window.onresize (and possible reorientation events on mobile devices) will catch the changes that flexbox makes to your children canvas(es).

Comment: Not only when the window is resized. The size of stretched elements can change when the size of another element on the same axis changes too. But anyway, I get your point; I'll track and inserts the needed callbacks myself. Thanks for your help!